# Joining tables in mongo db using aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**I'm trying to joining multiple tables in mongodb using lookup, pipeline,match. The problem is I have a table that I want extract the count of some fields.
Message table**

```
[
{
  "createdAt":"2023-03-05T10:47:09.646Z",
  "_id":"6404735c55bfc04cf96ecbbe",
  "message":"Testing",
  "userId":"62f13fd054f851ecc2c12e2a",
  "status":"submitted",
  "__v":0,
  "campaignId":1
},
{
  "createdAt":"2023-03-05T10:47:09.652Z",
  "_id":"640473a916577b4cfa9c9e29",
  "message":"Testing one",
  "userId":"62f13fd054f851ecc2c12e2a",
  "status":"delivered",
  "__v":0
  "campaignId":2
 },
 {
  "createdAt":"2023-03-05T10:47:09.695Z",
  "_id":"640473ae7052674cfed04602",
  "message":"Testing three",
  "userId":"62f13fd054f851ecc2c12e2a",
  "status":"rejected",
  "__v":0,
  "campaignId":3
},
{
  "createdAt":"2023-03-05T11:05:41.217Z",
  "_id":"6404779830ca9a5d3603c51a",
  "paymentMethod":"message 6",
  "userId":"62f13fd054f851ecc2c12e2a",
  "status":"submitted",
  "__v":0,
  "campaignId":4
 }
]
```

Existing query which works

```
Users.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: user._id } },
        
    { $lookup: {
      as: "userBilling",
      from: "sms_transactions",
      let: { user_id: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
         { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$userId",  "$$user_id" ] 
} } },
      ],       
    }},
  ])
```

Expected result is that I need to have counts in the message table such as

```
{
  "data":{
  "_id":"62f13fd054f851ecc2c12e2a",
  "userBilling":[],
  "userMessagesCount":[
    campaignId1:{
     "userId":"62f13fd054f851ecc2c12e2a",
     "submitted":"1",
     "delivered":"0",
     "rejected":"0"
     },
  campaignId2:{
         "userId":"62f13fd054f851ecc2c12e2a",
         "submitted":"0",
         "delivered":"1",
         "rejected":"0"
         },
    ]
  },
 }


User Collection

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
firstName: {type:String,required: true},
lastName: {type:String,required: true},
email:{ type:String, unique: true},
password: String,
phoneNumber:{ type:String, unique: true},
role:String,
status:String,
confirmed_phone:Boolean,
confirmed_email:Boolean,
country:{type:String,required: true},
token: String,
created_at:{type: Date,default: Date.now()},
},{ autoCreate: true});
mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Users');

Transaction Collection
var SMSTransactions = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
    amount: { type: Number, required: true },
    balanceBefore: { type: String },
    balanceAfter: { type: String },
    invoiceId: {
      type: String,
      default: () => MUUID.v4().toString("D"),
    },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    updatedAt: mongoose.Date,
    paymentMethod: { type: String, required: true },
    callbackUrl: String,
    status: String,
    country : String
  },
  { autoCreate: true }
);
mongoose.model("sms_transactions", SMSTransactions);
module.exports = mongoose.model("sms_transactions");

Messages Collection

var MessagesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
  message: {type:String,required: true},
  recipient: String,
  sender:String,
  status:String,
  bal_before:mongoose.Types.Decimal128,
  balance_after:mongoose.Types.Decimal128,
  created_at:{type: Date,default: Date.now()},
  updated_at: mongoose.Date,
  type:String,
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
  campaignId:String

},{ autoCreate: true});
mongoose.model('messages', MessagesSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('messages');
```

**How do I add lookup for the messages table to get the counts of the fields**

Comment: can you also put an example of the `user` collection and `userBilling`

Comment: That query works fine, I have to add the lookup for the messages

Comment: well, you can use $group, and `$sum` to fields that you want to be counted.

Comment: Can you add a query to that. That's the difficult part for me.

Comment: thats why i was asking you to put an example of the user collection and userBilling

Comment: Question has been updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252343/discussion-between-lutakyn-and-tobok-sitanggang).

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer. I have figured it out myself.

```
Users.aggregate([
{ $match: { _id: user._id } },
    
{ $lookup: {
  as: "userBilling",
  from: "sms_transactions",
  let: { user_id: "$_id" },
  pipeline: [
     { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$userId",  "$$user_id" ] 
} } },

$lookup: {
        as: "userMessagesCount",
        from: "messages",
        let: { id_msg_user: "$_id" },
        pipeline: [
          { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$userId", "$$id_msg_user"] } } },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: "$campaignId",
              submitted: {
                $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$status", "submitted"] }, 1, 0] 
              },
              },
              rejected: {
                $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$status", "rejected"] }, 1, 0] 
             },
              },
              accepted: {
                $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$status", "accepted"] }, 1, 0] 
              },
              },
              delivered: {
                $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$status", "delivered"] }, 1, 0] 
               },
              },
              },
            },
          },

        ],
      },
  ],       
}},
  ])
```